# Problems with getattr

Tags: python, pyqt, getattr

I've been tearing my hair out for the past hour trying to figure out a bug in the IRC-enabled program I'm working on, and after some debugging I've found that for some reason, getattr isn't working properly.  I have following test code:

```
def privmsg(self, user, channel, msg):
    #Callback for when the user receives a PRVMSG. 
    prvmsgText = textFormatter(msg,  
    self.factory.mainWindowInstance.ui.testWidget.ui.channelBrowser,
                                QColor(255, 0, 0, 127), 'testFont', 12)
    prvmsgText.formattedTextAppend()
```

and everything works perfectly.

Substitute the following, and the code breaks (doesn't output the text to a PyQT TextBrowser instance)

```
def privmsg(self, user, channel, msg):
    #Callback for when the user receives a PRVMSG. 
    prvmsgText = textFormatter(msg,  
    getattr(self.factory.mainWindowInstance.ui, 'testWidget.ui.channelBrowser'),
                                QColor(255, 0, 0, 127), 'testFont', 12)
    prvmsgText.formattedTextAppend()
```

Aren't these two ways of writing the second argument of the textFormatter function essentially equivalent? Why might this happen, and any ideas as to how I might approach a bug like this? Thanks.

Edit: Here is the (brief) textFormatter class, in case it helps:

```
from timeStamp import timeStamp

class textFormatter(object):
    '''
    Formats text for output to the tab widget text browser.
    '''
    def __init__(self,text,textBrowserInstance,textColor,textFont,textSize):
        self.text = text
        self.textBrowserInstance = textBrowserInstance
        self.textColor = textColor
        self.textFont = textFont
        self.textSize = textSize

    def formattedTextAppend(self):
        timestamp = timeStamp()
        self.textBrowserInstance.setTextColor(self.textColor)
        self.textBrowserInstance.setFontPointSize(self.textSize)
        self.textBrowserInstance.append(unicode(timestamp.stamp()) + unicode(self.text))
```

Comment: `self.factory.mainWindowInstance.ui.testWidget.ui.channelBrowser` dude, wtf? this isn't Java.

Comment: @Samus_ In PyQT where there's this hierarchy of widgets it seems that their attributes have to be accessed in a chain like that; if I have a main window instance that has a UI, and inside that main window are a bunch of widgets with their own UIs, and there are objects inside _those_ there needs to be some way to refer to which object you want specifically.  Maybe there's a better way to do it, but I'm still learning PyQT so perhaps I haven't found it yet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, getattr will get an attribute of an object. It can not traverse the hierarchy you gave in the string. The correct way would be:

```
getattr(self.factory.mainWindowInstance.ui.testWidget.ui, 'channelBrowser'),
                                QColor(255, 0, 0, 127), 'testFont', 12)
```

or

```
getattr(getattr(self.factory.mainWindowInstance.ui.testWidget, 'ui'), 'channelBrowser'),
                                    QColor(255, 0, 0, 127), 'testFont', 12)
```

Comment: Ah, ok.  So if I want to do a hierarchy, I guess I would have to iterate getattr.  Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I can't think of a use case where this would be the correct way of going about something in python.